# Azure Runbook - Input Blade

Tags: azure-automation, azure-runbook

I don't want the input blade (highlighted below) to be visible in my runbook job because I am passing some secrets or password as parameters to execute my runbook. If something else clicks input tile available under my runbook job or look over my shoulders my secrets will be revealed, so how do I disable input blade/tiles shown below?
If no options to hide the input blade then how to pass secrets as parameter to webhook runbook parameter? encryption/decryption or anything more relevant?

[image: Screenshot attached]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know, there is no way to hide the input blade. Even if one day the Azure release a new feature which you can use to hide the blade(if it exists, I think there also will be an option to show the blade again), your behavior will make no sense, the global admin can manage all the subscriptions in your tenant. If the global admin insists to see your input, he can access his goal anyway.

Some docs for you to refer:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/rbac-and-directory-admin-roles
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/elevate-access-global-admin

Comment: mentioned global admin as an example but over all needs is there any way to hide or remove input blade using power shell or rbac??

Comment: @thiru No, you could not hide or remove it. The closest way I can find is to pass the password as a securestring, but unfortunately it is not supported currently, this is the  feedback, you can vote for it : https://feedback.azure.com/forums/246290-automation/suggestions/11442894-make-securestring-a-supported-input-type-for-runbo